# Correct or complete a word based on context

Tags: nlp, prediction, word2vec

I am working on text normalization. I have descriptions of variables/attributes, which I need to convert to correct english.
A an example is shown below:
"This is the sta of the customer's order"
The word 'sta' above needs to be converted to 'status' based on the error and the context.

I tried out a character level encoder decoder architecture, but did not get good results.I need some direction on how to approach this problem.

input :"This is the sta of the customer's order"

output: "This is the status of the customer's order"

Answer (score 0):

This is called spell checking. There are ways to do so, one common way is to use minimum edit distance. An edit is one of these actions : adding a char, removing a char, replacing a char with another, transposing two adjacent chars. You can use edits to make new words out of mistaken words, and use a dictionary to see if the word really exists in English language. There may be more than 1 candidate for each incorrect word to choose from. There are also ways for candidate ranking.
Reading this paper may be a good start :

[A Survey of Spelling Error Detection and Correction Techniques](http://ijcttjournal.org/Volume4/issue-3/IJCTT-V4I3P134.pdf)